# Xcode 11 doesn't add iPhone6s Simulator

Tags: xcode, simulator, xcode11, iphone-6

I updated my iPhone6s and currently I am using iOS 13. I updated my Xcode as well and the current version is 11.0

My problem is all my previously installed simulators have gone after the Xcode update. I can see the devices but I can't install them. I am missing something or the IDE has changed and I can't see the magic + or add button.

[image]
[image: https://ibb.co/G9ksNh1]

Comment: You don't actually need a 6s simulator. Just use the iPhone 8 simulator. But if you really want one based on the 6s, see the duplicate for instructions on how to add a specific simulator.

Comment: I found the problem. In Xcode 11.0 if you don't create a new simulator device with iOS 13 and add it to the list, it doesn't show the previously added devices. It is I guess a bug. I created iPhone 6s with iOS 13 then my list have been updated. Now I can see all my devices including iPhone 5s ones.